# Как добавить поля для сериализации, не изменяя саму модель?

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

Как можно в DRF изменить имена полей модели и добавить новые (для отображения в API (json)), не меняя при этом саму модель?

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так?

```
class Person(Model):
    name = CharField(...)
    slug = CharField(...)

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name + self.slug


class PersonSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    full_name = serializers.CharField(source='get_name', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('slug', 'full_name')
```

Изменить поле еще можно, переопределив метод [to_representation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#to_representationself-obj):

```
def to_representation(self, obj):
    old_repr = super().to_representation(obj)
    old_repr['NEW FIELD'] = old_repr['OLD FIELD']
    return old_repr
```